# rails authlogic: Why is UserSessionsController#destroy called twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/) to implement authentication with authlogic. Everything went quite fine until I tried to logout. I always got this error message:

undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

for this code:

```
# DELETE /user_sessions/1
# DELETE /user_sessions/1.xml
def destroy
  @user_session = UserSession.find
  @user_session.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(:users, :notice => 'Goodbye!') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
end
```

Using the debugger, I've found out that `destroy` is called twice when I click on logout. So I added a check if `@user_session` is `nil` and all is fine. The thing is: I'm not experienced enough in rails to find out *why* `destroy` is called twice. According to the tutorial, this should not be the case.

Following, I'll attach some information which might be related:

_header.html.erb : here's the link to logout

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id)%>
  <%= link_to "Logout", :logout%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path%> |
  <%= link_to "Login", :login %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb: map /logout to UserSessionController#destroy (this deviates a bit from the tutorial since "match" without "via:" caused an error):

```
  Notenschrank::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, :user_sessions
  match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login, via: [:get]
  match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout, via: [:get]
```

(Hmm, could it be that `get` is not the right method? The comment from the scaffolded code mentions `delete`…)

And here, as one big chunk, the two backtraces from `destroy`. I'd rather append it as a textfile, but I don't know how :s

```
Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 12:29:29 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#destroy as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
/home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:25
@user_session && @user_session.destroy

[20, 29] in /home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb
   20    # DELETE /user_sessions/1
   21    # DELETE /user_sessions/1.json
   22    def destroy
   23      @user_session = UserSession.find
   24      debugger
=> 25      @user_session && @user_session.destroy
   26
   27      respond_to do |format|
   28        format.html { redirect_to :users, notice: 'Bye!' }
   29        format.json { head :no_content }
(rdb:114) where
--> #0 UserSessionsController.destroy
       at line /home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:25
    #1 ActionController::ImplicitRender.send_action(method#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
    #2 AbstractController::Base.process_action(method_name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189
    #3 ActionController::Rendering.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
    #4 UserSessionsController._run__3910799261545475014__process_action__callbacks
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:18
    #5 ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run_callbacks(kind#Symbol)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
    #6 AbstractController::Callbacks.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
    #7 ActionController::Rescue.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
    #8 ActiveSupport::Notifications::Instrumenter.instrument(name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:31
    #9 ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159
    #10 ActionController::Instrumentation.process_action
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
    #11 ActionController::ParamsWrapper.process_action
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245
    #12 ActiveRecord::Railties::ControllerRuntime.process_action(action#String)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
    #13 AbstractController::Base.process(action#String)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136
    #14 AbstractController::Rendering.process
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44
    #15 ActionController::Metal.dispatch(name#String, request#ActionDispatch::Request,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195
    #16 ActionController::RackDelegation.dispatch(action#String, request#ActionDispatch::Request,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13
    #17 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.dispatch(controller#Class, action#String,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:231
    #18 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.dispatch(controller#Class, action#String,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80
    #19 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48
    #20 ActionDispatch::Journey::Router.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71
    #21 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655
    #22 RequestStore::Middleware.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9
    #23 Rack::ETag.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
    #24 Rack::ConditionalGet.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25
    #25 Rack::Head.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11
    #26 ActionDispatch::ParamsParser.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27
    #27 ActionDispatch::Flash.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241
    #28 Rack::Session::Abstract::ID.context(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225
    #29 Rack::Session::Abstract::ID.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220
    #30 ActionDispatch::Cookies.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486
    #31 ActiveRecord::QueryCache.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36
    #32 ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626
    #33 ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:369
    #34 ActionDispatch::Callbacks._run__3212301349710016163__call__callbacks
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:29
    #35 ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run_callbacks(kind#Symbol)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
    #36 ActionDispatch::Callbacks.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
    #37 ActionDispatch::Reloader.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64
    #38 ActionDispatch::RemoteIp.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76
    #39 ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17
    #40 ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30
    #41 Rails::Rack::Logger.call_app(request#ActionDispatch::Request, env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38
    #42 ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter.tagged
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:21
    #43 ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.tagged
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67
    #44 Rails::Rack::Logger.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21
    #45 ActionDispatch::RequestId.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21
    #46 Rack::MethodOverride.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21
    #47 Rack::Runtime.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
    #48 ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83
    #49 Rack::Lock.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17
    #50 ActionDispatch::Static.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64
    #51 Rails::Engine.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511
    #52 Rails::Application.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97
    #53 Rack::Lock.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17
    #54 Rack::ContentLength.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14
    #55 Rails::Rack::Debugger.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/debugger.rb:20
    #56 Rack::Handler::WEBrick.service(req#WEBrick::HTTPRequest, res#WEBrick::HTTPResponse,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60
    #57 WEBrick::HTTPServer.service(req#WEBrick::HTTPRequest, res#WEBrick::HTTPResponse,...)
        at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138
    #58 WEBrick::HTTPServer.run(sock#TCPSocket)
        at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94
    #59  at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191
(rdb:114) cont
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 46402ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 12:30:16 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 35.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 12:30:16 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#destroy as HTML
/home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:25
@user_session && @user_session.destroy

[20, 29] in /home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb
   20    # DELETE /user_sessions/1
   21    # DELETE /user_sessions/1.json
   22    def destroy
   23      @user_session = UserSession.find
   24      debugger
=> 25      @user_session && @user_session.destroy
   26
   27      respond_to do |format|
   28        format.html { redirect_to :users, notice: 'Bye!' }
   29        format.json { head :no_content }
(rdb:114) where
--> #0 UserSessionsController.destroy
       at line /home/markus/projects/notenschrank/app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:25
    #1 ActionController::ImplicitRender.send_action(method#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
    #2 AbstractController::Base.process_action(method_name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189
    #3 ActionController::Rendering.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
    #4 UserSessionsController._run__3910799261545475014__process_action__callbacks
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:18
    #5 ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run_callbacks(kind#Symbol)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
    #6 AbstractController::Callbacks.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
    #7 ActionController::Rescue.process_action
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
    #8 ActiveSupport::Notifications::Instrumenter.instrument(name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:31
    #9 ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(name#String)
       at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159
    #10 ActionController::Instrumentation.process_action
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
    #11 ActionController::ParamsWrapper.process_action
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245
    #12 ActiveRecord::Railties::ControllerRuntime.process_action(action#String)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
    #13 AbstractController::Base.process(action#String)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136
    #14 AbstractController::Rendering.process
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44
    #15 ActionController::Metal.dispatch(name#String, request#ActionDispatch::Request,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195
    #16 ActionController::RackDelegation.dispatch(action#String, request#ActionDispatch::Request,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13
    #17 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.dispatch(controller#Class, action#String,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:231
    #18 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.dispatch(controller#Class, action#String,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80
    #19 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48
    #20 ActionDispatch::Journey::Router.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71
    #21 ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655
    #22 RequestStore::Middleware.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9
    #23 Rack::ETag.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
    #24 Rack::ConditionalGet.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25
    #25 Rack::Head.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11
    #26 ActionDispatch::ParamsParser.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27
    #27 ActionDispatch::Flash.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241
    #28 Rack::Session::Abstract::ID.context(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225
    #29 Rack::Session::Abstract::ID.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220
    #30 ActionDispatch::Cookies.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486
    #31 ActiveRecord::QueryCache.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36
    #32 ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626
    #33 ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:369
    #34 ActionDispatch::Callbacks._run__3212301349710016163__call__callbacks
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:29
    #35 ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run_callbacks(kind#Symbol)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
    #36 ActionDispatch::Callbacks.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
    #37 ActionDispatch::Reloader.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64
    #38 ActionDispatch::RemoteIp.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76
    #39 ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17
    #40 ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30
    #41 Rails::Rack::Logger.call_app(request#ActionDispatch::Request, env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38
    #42 ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter.tagged
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:21
    #43 ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.tagged
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67
    #44 Rails::Rack::Logger.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21
    #45 ActionDispatch::RequestId.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21
    #46 Rack::MethodOverride.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21
    #47 Rack::Runtime.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
    #48 ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83
    #49 Rack::Lock.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17
    #50 ActionDispatch::Static.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64
    #51 Rails::Engine.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511
    #52 Rails::Application.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97
    #53 Rack::Lock.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17
    #54 Rack::ContentLength.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14
    #55 Rails::Rack::Debugger.call(env#Hash)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/debugger.rb:20
    #56 Rack::Handler::WEBrick.service(req#WEBrick::HTTPRequest, res#WEBrick::HTTPResponse,...)
        at line /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60
    #57 WEBrick::HTTPServer.service(req#WEBrick::HTTPRequest, res#WEBrick::HTTPResponse,...)
        at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138
    #58 WEBrick::HTTPServer.run(sock#TCPSocket)
        at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94
    #59  at line /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191
```

And the software versions:

```
% rails --version
Rails 4.0.0
% ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p457 (2014-03-03) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
% bundle show authlogic
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/authlogic-3.4.1
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: this is the code for UsersController#index:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Comment: It looks like you're just clicking the button twice. There's nothing in there to indicate 'one button press calls the action twice'. The two requests are completely standalone, a minute apart.

Comment: Can you share the code for `UsersController#index` action. Also, if you have defined any callbacks i.e., `before_filter` or `after_filter` in `UsersController` or in `ApplicationController` then share them too.

Comment: sevenseacat, I surely didn't press the button twice every time I tried this…

Comment: Kirti Thorat, I added the code for UsersController#index. There are no filters in UsersController or ApplicationController.

Comment: I just tried this with firefox instead of chromium and what shall I say? With firefox, `GET "/logout"` is called only once, as it should. WTF???